# how to dynamically load the aspx page in div tag ?

Tags: asp.net, url, html

Hi everybody...
                I am trying to load the contents of one aspx page into div tag of another aspx page, i dont want to use jquery for it. can anybody please suggest me the server side solution to load the div tag dynamically on click of button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To do it server side your only option is building User Control and put that control inside or instead of the `<div>`. The control can fetch the `.aspx` output using something like HttpRequest or WebClient.

Answer (score 5):

Just get the page it self and send it to the control

in **HTML** file

```
<div class="code">
    <pre><asp:Literal id="litCode" runat="server /></pre>
</div>
```

in **CS** file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        populate();
}

private void populate()
{
    litCode.Text = getSoureCodeFromFile("http://localhost:21300/Search.aspx");
}

private string getSoureCodeFromFile(string url)
{
    string r = "";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        r = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
    return r;
}
```