# Load another asp.net page into current page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using ASP.NET with C#, I would like to load the content of another page into my current page.

I have a main div `id="maindiv"` on one page with a header above it. The header contains clickable links that route to the same url with a get variable like `http://www.mainpage.com&page=nextpage`. I would like to use the page get variable in a switch case to load from a specified page into maindiv. I can do the switch case bit fine, but how do I load the response from another page?

Comment: here a good solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467488/how-to-dynamically-load-the-aspx-page-in-div-tag

Comment: do you want to read data from another page ?

Comment: Are you looking for a wizard-like functionality?

Comment: @HassanBoutougha would this allow for the page to have it's own codebehind?

Comment: the solution use a literal control to display aspx page it is more usefull than work with iframe

Comment: @waqarjanjua data and functionality with codebehind. Essentially running another page within. I've got a header with nav, a footer with a jquery ticker tape of data, and the middle section which will house these pages. I'm trying to avoid recreating the static structure for each page.

Comment: of course because it download all javascript transcription of your page

Comment: Use a [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)? Or [jQuery UI ajax tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax)?

Comment: @jrummel MasterPage looks interesting. I'll give that a try Monday and see if it works. If it does, I'll have you drop it in as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep the same layout (header, navigation, footer, etc) for all of your pages. ASP.NET 2.0 introduced Master Pages, which are basically layout files that allow you to create Content pages that fill in place holders in the layout.

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the
>   pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and
>   feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a
>   group of pages) in your application. You can then create individual
>   content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users
>   request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce
>   output that combines the layout of the master page with the content
>   from the content page.

Here's a sample from the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></div>
        <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content page:

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 1):

a possible solution is

set an iframe 
like in http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37635.aspx
you will take your query string parameter to set source of iframe

```
frame1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.live.com" ;
```

in code behind

```
frame1.Attributes["src"] = nextpage ;
```

Comment: you have right the solution display source, i find it elegant but after you have to traduce it...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either using Panels and showing based on URL variable or use .ASCX user control files and load those based on URL variable if you need code behind logic.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" visible="false">
    page 1...
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" visible="false">
    page 2...
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I'd rather not use panels. Makes it messy and I've trying to seperate each "page" on into it's own file. I haven't used .ascx user controls before. How do those work?

Answer (score 0):

This related post might provide a solution to your problem:

[How to display an ASPX in another ASPX's DIV dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099214/how-to-display-an-aspx-in-another-aspxs-div-dynamically-at-runtime)